# Define labelled line using Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I am trying to create a new shape called labelled line. something like below picture. I decided to use Fabric JS and  Extending the `fabric.line` class.

#### New class extends Line

```
var LabelledLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {

  type: 'lline',
  // initialize can be of type function(options) or function(property, options), like for text.
  // no other signatures allowed.
  initialize: function(options) {
    options || (options = { });

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    this.set('label', options.label || '');
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      label: this.get('label')
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

    //ctx.font = '20px Helvetica';
    //ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    // ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
  }
});
```

#### Invocation

```
var l = LabelledLine({
    coords: [250, 125, 250, 175], label:'Label'
  })
  canvas.add(l);
```

#### Problem

How do achieve label exactly between the line or just left or right of line ? or next to line
looks like, I am not extending it properly, anything I am missing here? I am not able to see the line without label also.

Error

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at klass (fabric.js:2238)
    at Image.background.onload
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Edge = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {

    type: 'edge',
    // initialize can be of type function(options) or function(property, options), like for text.
    // no other signatures allowed.
    initialize: function(points, options){
      options = options || {};
      this.points = points || [];

      this.callSuper('initialize',points, options);
      this.set('label', options.label || '');
    },

    toObject: function() {
      return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
        label: this.get('label')
      });
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
      this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

      ctx.font = '9px Helvetica';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
      ctx.fillText(this.label,  -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
      // ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
    }
  });


  var lr = new Edge([ 250, 125, 500, 175 ], {
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    selectable: true,
    evented: true,
    hasBorders:false,
    cornerStyle:'circle',
    lockScalingX: true,
    lockScalingY:true,
    label: '1'
  });
  canvas.add(lr);

};
```

https://codepen.io/ajayramesh/pen/NWNpaRW